# VS Code//GitHub Discard All Changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new programmer. I have several hundred files that are now pending changes in my vs code. I was about to remove them with the "discard all changes" when I got uneasy and came here to double-check that decision. Glad I did, holy heck. How do I remove these changes without permanently deleting the files?  Please help. Thank You.

Comment: like you want to delete some sort of code temporarily?

Comment: discard changes will not delete the files it will only revert them back to how they were before your last commit

Comment: in any case make a backup of your files then try the operation

Comment: That makes way more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your git repo to its initial state and remove all your changes, you can run

```
git checkout .
```

Run this command in VSCode Terminal, which can be opened using ***Ctrl + `*** (Control + backtick(key below escape))

Read the link below to understand what this command does:
https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+checkout+.